# Why does {} work with an integer but set() doesn't?

Tags: python, python-3.x, set

When I type `{5}` in the Console, the result I get is a set:

```
>>> {3}
{3}
```

Whereas `set(5)` results in an error:

```
>>> set(5)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

[`{}` or the `set()` function can both be used to create sets.](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets). So why is this happening?

Comment: [set](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set) takes an iterable, such as a list, and not an integer

Comment: For the same reason `[3]` and `list(3)` aren't the same.

Comment: What do you mean by "why"? Are you asking about the *advantage* of the ``{}`` *syntax*, about the *difference* of the underlying constructs, or something else?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I understood from the answer why set(5) doesn't work, but why is {5} functioning then?

Comment: From the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets `Note: to create an empty set you have to use set(), not {}; the latter creates an empty dictionary`

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh That's for an empty set. `type({5})` is `<class 'set'>`

Comment: @Snow `{5}` isn't a function call; it's a set *literal*, just like `5` is an `int` literal.

Comment: `set` *could* have been written to take an arbitrary number of arguments, so that `set(1,2,3) == {1,2,3}` and `set(5) == {5}`, but then you run into the problem of sets of iterables. While `set("ab", "cd")` would clearly be `{"ab", "cd"}`, what should `set("ab")` be? Is that a single set with a 2-letter string, or a 2-element set of single-letter strings?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because [the definition of `set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set) is:

```
class set([iterable])
```

It doesn't take single individual values, it takes *one* iterable of values. E.g.:

```
set([5, 6, 7])
```

You'd use a literal when you hardcode a fixed number of values or variables:

```
{'foo', bar, baz()}
```

And you'd use the `set` constructor when you have *one* iterable that you want to "unpack" into a set:

```
set(baz)
set(foo(bar) for bar in baz)
set(map(foo, baz))
```

Comment: 'k' is also a single individual value, yet `set('k')` results in a set. Do you mean numeric data types?

Comment: @Snow `[5,6,7]` is *also* a single individual value, but it's an iterable value. `'k'` is *also* an iterable value, one that (oddly enough) contains exactly one string, `'k'`. (Strings are weird in Python, due to the lack of a distinct `char` type.)

Comment: Strings are *iterable*. `set('foo')` results in the set `{'f', 'o'}`.

Comment: @chepner deceze Understood it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When you define a set instance over multiple values, then values are not necessarily concrete. For example, they could be lazily computed by a generator:

```
values = (a%1 for a in range(2500000))
my_set1 = set(values)  # values can be *any* iterable type
```

This is memory-efficient, as the `set` only ever contains up to 2 values. Duplicates are eliminated as they arise.

If `set` would take individual values, you would have to `*`-unpack the lazy iterable into a temporary tuple. The intermediate tuple would contain all 2500000 values.

```
def inefficient_set(*items):  # items is an intermediate tuple
    return set(items)

values = (a%1 for a in range(2500000))
my_set2 = inefficient_set(*values)
```

With `set` taking an iterable, you use an intermediate container only when you need it.

---

When you define a literal set of multiple values, then all values are already concrete. Similarly, when you define a literal set of lazy values, then these are also concrete.

```
my_set3 = {0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1}            # values are known to be concrete
my_set4 = {a%1 for a in range(2500000)} # values are known to be lazy
```

In this case, requiring an *iterable* would require a useless intermediate container. With `{}` taking individual values, you use an intermediate container only when you need it.

---

The important part to consider is that `{...}` is *syntax* whereas `set(...)` is a regular *type instantiation*. In Python, syntax is static whereas types are dynamic. This allows to statically distinguish `{a, b, c, ...}` literals of concrete values from `{... for ... in ...}` comprehensions.

Comment: This isn't really relevant. It's a *bonus* that `set` can discard duplicates as it reads them from a lazy iterable, but you can also write `set([0,1,0,1,0,1])` and get a two-element set.

Comment: To note, you could and would also write a set comprehension… `{a%1 for a in range(2500000)}`

Comment: @chepner The point is that with ``set`` and ``{}`` working this way, you *can* use the optimal path but you are free not to. If they worked the other way, you could not use the optimal path.

Comment: @deceze would the time complexity of the comprehension be the same as `set((a%1 for a in range(2500000)))`? Or lower?

Comment: @deceze I have chosen a generator expression just for demonstration. The point is that the argument to ``set`` could be any type, whereas the type of argument to ``{..}`` is statically defined by syntax.

Comment: @Snow The complexity is the same either way, and practically both do the same behind the scenes - feeding a generator to the set constructor. In principle, set could be overridden in your case, though. Note that ``pypy`` can optimise the ``{}`` literal to about double the speed of using ``set``.